# How to bind reference to stack allocated class in class constructor?

Tags: c++

I have this class

```
class HumanA
{
    public:

    HumanA(std::string name, Weapon weapon);
    ~HumanA(void);

    inline void     attack(void)
    {
        std::cout << _name << " attacks with his " << _weapon.getType();
    }


    private:

    std::string     _name;
    Weapon          &_weapon;
};
```

and this constructor

```
HumanA::HumanA(std::string name, Weapon weapon) : _name(ft::strcapitalize(name)), _weapon(weapon)
{
}
```

and I get this error at compilation

```
HumanA.cpp:15:91: error: binding reference member '_weapon' to stack allocated
      parameter 'weapon' [-Werror,-Wdangling-field]
  ...name, Weapon weapon) : _name(ft::strcapitalize(name)), _weapon(weapon)
                                                                    ^~~~~~
./HumanA.hpp:35:12: note: reference member declared here
        Weapon                  &_weapon;
                                 ^
1 error generated.
```

isn't it possible to have a reference to stack allocated memory? This error seems weird to me.

Comment: Your passed `weapon` argument exists on the stack *only* for the duration of the constructor. When that has completed, the stack will be 'reset' and the reference will then be invalid.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to accomplish without further code, but you *can* have a reference to a stack-allocated object, so long as you never have the possibility of using it when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Using `const &` would be a better idea. But keep in mind that will also bind to `rvalue`

Comment: @AdrianMole Please don't answer in comments, thanks

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I was asking for clarity.

Comment: Nope, you weren't.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings *Not sure what you're trying to accomplish without further code...*

Comment: @AdrianMole Now the rest of it. _"Your passed weapon argument exists on the stack only for the duration of the constructor. When that has completed, the stack will be 'reset' and the reference will then be invalid. [..] you can have a reference to a stack-allocated object, so long as you never have the possibility of using it when it goes out of scope."_ That is the answer to the question. Please do not provide answers in comments. Cheers and have a good day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think:

1. What is the scope and "time of living" of `Weapon weapon` object?
2. What is the answer to the same question for the member  `Weapon &_weapon`?

The answer to the first question is this: `weapon` exists as long as the constructor is executing. This is a stack-allocated variable that ceases to exist the moment the constructor finishes its job.

The answer to the second question is: member `_weapon` exists as long as the object that contains this member exists.

So the time of living of `weapon` is *shorter* that that of `_weapon`.
Now, what happens when you bind a reference to an object whose time of living is shorter than that of the reference? Well, you'll get a dangling reference. A reference to a memory you don't own. A serious bug that is difficult to spot and difficult to trace unless some special diagnostoc tools have been used, like valgind. In other words, you are free to write this code, but you can access the member only while your program is inside the constructor. This is not something you've intended, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You are binding a reference to a parameter value.  Once the constructor has completed, that parameter is destroyed and the reference is **guaranteed to dangle**.

Change the parameter to a reference.

```
HumanA(std::string name, Weapon &weapon);
```

Comment: This is *probably* what the OP needs but, without clarification and seeing how that constructor is called, it is only a guess.

Answer (score 0):

> isn't it possible to have a reference to stack allocated memory

Of course you can. Except that the problem here is that this "stack allocated memory" disappears when the constructor returns, and attempting to use it from that point [results in nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) and your compiler is smart enough to detect this bug.

Parameters to all functions, including constructors, get destroyed when the function/constructor returns. Capturing a reference to them does not change that.

If you were to declare a reference ***in the constructor***, to its parameter, and use it only in the constructor, nobody will complain about it.

Answer (score 0):

> isn't it possible to have a reference to stack allocated memory? This error seems weird to me.

It certainly is, but you have to make sure the original object lives at least as long as the reference does. Yours… doesn't. It's a by-value constructor parameter that's effectively local to the constructor, so the reference is left dangling pretty much immediately.

Usually you'd only be getting a *warning* about this, but your compiler is in `-Werror` mode, which turns warnings into errors. Good thing too!

If you take a reference into the constructor too, then you'll be binding the reference to the original, original object, which is presumably what you want.

If it's *not* what you want, if you wanted the class to own a copy of the `Weapon`, then just forget the reference and `std::move` the constructor argument into the member (or just copy it again if it's cheap to do so).